# How do we use lowercase `\mathcal` or `\mathscr` in latex overleaf?

Tags: amsart, mathcal

I tried `\usepackage{bickham}` in [latex overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/project) but I get:

```
LaTeX Error: File `bickham.sty' not found.
```

How do we get a lower case `\mathcal` in latex overleaf? For instance, for:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{bickham} 

\begin{document}

    \mathcal{r}

\end{document}
```

how do we get a cursive r instead of an error sign?

Comment: As far as I remember the `bickham` bundle only contains the fonts. There is no `bickham` package: the interface is provided by the `mathalfa` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use stix2 for example

[image]

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{stix2} 

\begin{document}

    HERE: $\mathscr{rstuvw}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarisle I notice `stix2` changes the font of the text. How do we revert the font to normal.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the Bickham font installed on your system (it's a commercial font, and I don't have access to it on my system), the following code should work:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[scr=bickham]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}
$\mathscr{abc}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- All good now. Thanks for clearing this up.